# Get the right data at the right place

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a Json file and was able to extract some values from it and sum them up. I want to be able to put the result to the right key but can't figure it out.
Below is my code:

```
from builtins import print
import json
import jmespath
from collections import Counter

const = ['constituency A','constituency B','constituency C']
region = ['region A','region B','reigon C']
poll = ['POLLING STATION A','POLLING STATION B','POLLING STATION C','POLLING STATION   Z','POLLING STATION F']

fake = {'transaction':[{'region A':{'constituency A':{
    'POLLING STATION A':{'PARTY A':10,'PARTY B':20,'PARTY C':30,'PARTY D':40},
    'POLLING STATION Z':{'PARTY A':50,'PARTY B':60,'PARTY C':70,'PARTY D':80},
    'POLLING STATION B':{'PARTY A':90,'PARTY B':100,'PARTY C':110,'PARTY D':120},
    'POLLING STATION F':{'PARTY A':190,'PARTY B':1100,'PARTY C':1110,'PARTY D':1120},},
    }}]}

 a = json.dumps((fake))
 p = json.loads(a)
 j = jmespath.search('transaction[*]',p)

 ham = []
 man = set()
 for new_d in j:
     for k,v in new_d.items():
         for i_k,i_v in v.items():
             for w,c in i_v.items():
                 if w in poll and i_k in const and k in region:
                     ham.append(c)
 up = len(ham)
 i= 0
 a1=Counter()
 while i < up:
     a1 += Counter(ham[i])
     i+=1

  print(a1)
```

So this is what I wanted to do, the result which is a1 will be placed a dictionary this way =>`[ {'region A':{'constituency A':{'PARTY D': 1360, 'PARTY C': 1320, 'PARTY B': 1280, 'PARTY A': 340}}}]`
When vote for constituency B in region A is also calculated, the result will be added to region A with constituency B as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've iterated over each dict and counted the party votes for each constituency.

```
fake = {
    'transaction': [
        { 'region A': 
            { 'constituency A': 
                {
                    'POLLING STATION A': 
                        {'PARTY A': 10, 'PARTY B': 20, 'PARTY C': 30, 'PARTY D': 40},
                    'POLLING STATION Z': 
                        {'PARTY A': 50, 'PARTY B': 60, 'PARTY C': 70, 'PARTY D': 80},
                    'POLLING STATION B': 
                        {'PARTY A': 90, 'PARTY B': 100, 'PARTY C': 110, 'PARTY D': 120},
                    'POLLING STATION F': 
                        {'PARTY A': 190, 'PARTY B': 1100, 'PARTY C': 1110, 'PARTY D': 1120},
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}

data = fake['transaction'][0]

total_result = {}

for region, constituencies in data.items():
    total_result[region] = {}
    for constituency, stations in constituencies.items():
        party_votes = {}
        for station, parties in stations.items():
            for party, vote in parties.items():
                party_votes[party] = party_votes.get(party, 0) + vote
        total_result[region][constituency] = party_votes

print(total_result)
```

prints

```
{'region A': {'constituency A': {'PARTY A': 340, 'PARTY B': 1280, 'PARTY C': 1320, 'PARTY D': 1360}}}
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, your solution is very helpful.